# Prime lens is over-exposed fully open, when in full daylight

Tags: bokeh, overexposure

I bought a Lumix f/1.7 25mm prime (H-H025), to use with my OM-D E10.3

When fully open on a bright sunny day, with the ISO set to 200 my shutter speed flashes at 4000 to indicate it's out of range. If I drop the EV down to -1 the images are still washed out/overexposed.

Other than going back a few stops until I get an acceptable shutter speed, what else can I do to ensure a good level of exposure, and a sweet sweet bokeh?

Should I be going all the way down to -5 EV? And if I do, what (if any) side-effects will that have on image quality/sharpness on the focal point?

Comment: You need to learn about the [exposure triangle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6598/38159). You need to stay away from exposure compensation until you understand its use case, and only use it when it should be used. You should use one of the A or S exposure modes I think, if you want properly exposed photographs. Don't use M mode, unless there's something about the scene that is fooling your meter.

Comment: Re your last line... it looks to me like you are conflating the quite independent issues of metering and focus.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve shallow depth of field (which I think might be your ultimate goal, even though you haven't explicitly said it), maybe take a look at this question: [How can I get dramatic shallow DOF with a kit lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5493) It has helpful information. In my opinion, you have to get proper exposure first, before trying to be creative.

Comment: Exposure Compensation has absolutely nothing to do directly with the gain control of the sensor. The sensor gain is controlled by the ISO setting. [Exposure Compensation (EC) is a way of controlling the camera's metering system so that we can tell it we want our photo to look brighter or darker than an average scene.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/95051/15871)

Comment: Here are some more questions that have useful information: [How properly expose a long exposure in daylight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/91581) [Why are my long-exposure photos (with ND filter) overexposed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86492)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are neutral density filters and how do I use them to create long exposures in daylight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/what-are-neutral-density-filters-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-create-long-exposures)

Answer (score 6):

If you're already at your maximum shutter speed, and your lowest ISO, and you don't want to reduce your aperture, then you might try adding an ND filter. Or wait for (or create) lower-light conditions.

Comment: ND filter is a good idea, I'll look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching to electronic shutter, then you can probably achive a faster shutter speed of 16000.